# Zend Framework 2 default module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF1 you did not have to include the module in the URL; if it was not provided, it would default to... the default module. How can this be accomplished in ZF2? I have used the skeleton application to get up and running, but it seems as if I always need to include the module name, e.g. `/application/controller/action`.

I figured I could work around this by creating a route with two "placeholders"; controller and action, and then set the default module to "application". I would then put this in `/config/autoload/global.php` (or perhaps `/config/application.config.php`) so that the route applies for all of my application. However, I am getting the error message that the URL could not be matched by routing, even if I hard code the route to something like `/user/index`.

I tried the code below.

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'nomodule' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:controller/:action',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'module' => 'Application' // Not sure of the syntax here
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

As I wrote as a comment, I am not sure if my problem is with the defaults syntax, but I wouldn't think so as the same happens if I hard code the route and remove all defaults. I also tried to experiment with it based on examples in the skeleton application, but without luck. Am I going about it the wrong way? Is there a better approach? Or did I just make a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** For the code to make it work, see the answer. For an explanation of *how* it works, read [this article](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/removing-module-from-url-in-zend-framework-2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note: Explicit routes are strongly recommended over wildcard.

You used Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal route type in your attempt, as you might guess it is literal, ie exact match. To make it work you need segment route type.

[Check `application` route in Zend Skeleton Application config](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L27) and it's child route `default`.
It does exactly what you are trying to do.

As for modules - there is no such thing as 'module' from your code perspective. Module registers resources on startup and it is no longer relevant after that point.
In zf2 you specify exact controller by class or alias name under which controller registered with controllerManager

```
// module\Application\config\module.config.php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index',
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\User' => 'Application\Controller\UserController'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: I'd add an hint that every controller must be listed in the invokables, to have them parsed out of the url the symbol used in invokables must match the symbol used in the url.

Comment: @SamuelHerzog it is not required to be in `invokables`, it can be configured as factory too. But yeah, it must be in ControllerManager.

Comment: of course, but since you used invokables i thought it would make more sense to point that out than to add additional information, that's your task :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to make small adjustments for the code to work, but you pointed me in the right direction. I have edited the code in your answer to reflect my edits. I removed a slash from the segments route (since it is a child route of the `/` route) and set the `__NAMESPACE__` to my controller directory. By doing this, I can write `localhost/user` in the URL and have it map to `Application\Controller\User` instead of having to change my controller keys to match those in the URL (and by doing so opening up for module controller collisions).

Comment: I was expecting this code to work with following set of URLs: /application/index/index; /application/index (action is default); /application (controller and action are default); /index/index (module is default); /index (module and action are default); But it doesn't... So in my opinion it's not correct answer... Of course I understand that there is no such thing as module, but let's say they exist in path.

Comment: Hey @Andy0708 - check my answer, as it works on all URLs I pointed out. I will not downvote Xerkus answer as it works for some URLs as well. Also his theoretical explanation led me to my solution.

Comment: @Carlos example here is for segment route and not for bringing old behavior in zf2

Comment: copypaste your config, change the name of controller and get this: 
The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
currency(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: currency)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comment under @Xerkus answer, it doesn't work for all URLs:

```
/application/index/index
/application/index
/application
/index/index
/index
/
```

I have added also `testAction()` to `IndexController` and `TestController` with same actions as `IndexController`, so I could test my solution on following routes as well:

```
/index/test
/test/index
/test/test
/test
```

So after some research ([here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-495) mainly) I prepared solution working for all of them. I will paste my whole `module.config.php` array:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'noModule' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Test' => 'Application\Controller\TestController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

In comparison with Zend 2 Skeleteon Application config I've added `noModule` route, and new `controller invokable` - `test`. Of course `noModule` route includes `Application/Controller` namespace, so basing on this fact, you can set whatever default module you need. Now it works as it should.

Of course remember that your `noModule` route should be defined in first module from `application.config.php` to ensure that it will always take precedence. Also remember that default module solution should be done carefully, to avoid conflicts between controllers and modules names, e.g. if you name your next module `Index`, then clearly you will have a naming conflict with `IndexController` in `Application` module.

Comment: while this works, it is conceptually wrong approach. You are trying to bring aspects of zf1 in zf2 application. In zf2 specific routes are strongly favored and there are many reasons for that, amongst them is the separation of concern: your code in controller/view layers will depend on route name only and not on route name + controller [+ action], hence controller and/or action can be easily swapped in one place. Another issue you've just got yourself into is that your route will incorrectly match great deal of URIs, resulting in incorrect controller resolution and huge amount of WTFs.

Comment: @Xerkus - I agree with you that it's not the way it meant to be, and it's mixing zf1 approach with zf2 architecture. That's why I have written you need to be carefull and look for conflicts. I didn't say I will use it in any project - I simply asked the question. Sometimes you can't follow best possible approach or design pattern, and I know, that you as a developer faced such situations before as well. That's why I spent some time to make this code works. And as I wrote I agree with your theoretical explanation, which actually helped me to understand few things in ZF2 routing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ZF in general and I just started learning it, so tried this and it worked for me. Just to be sure, u want to change your default module when you go to your domain URL and don't type in a controller name, right?

Go to your module.config.php

```php
 'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album WITH CONTROLLER IN URL' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'album WITHOUT CONTROLLER IN URL' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'SET IT AS YOUR HOMEPAGE' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: your constraints have to match an placeholder in the route (e.g. /:action) to have any effect.