# Routes with multiple modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2, routes

I'm currently working in ZF2 and need some help.
Unfortunately I can only find examples set the routes for the case that there is only one module. Or the example has still the application module in it, with dynamic segment routes. I want to totally remove the application module and only have my own modules running an configure all routing in them.

I have two modules:
CLFrontend,
CLBackend

My application config looks like this:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ClFrontend',
        'ClBackend'
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),

);
```

I want to register my 2 own modules there. The routing should now look someway like this:

everything under / should go to the frontend module excerpt /backend

> /  --> IndexController --> indexaction
>
> /controller1 --> Controller1Controller -> indexaction
>
> /controller1/add --> Controller1Controller --> addaction
>
> /controller1/add/1/ --> COntroller1Controller --> addaction --> item 1

Now should everything under /backend route to the backend module

> /backend  --> BackendIndexController --> indexaction
>
> /backend/controller1 --> BackendController1Controller -> indexaction
>
> /backend/controller1/add --> BackendController1Controller -->
>   addaction
>
> /backend/controller1/add/1/ --> BackendCOntroller1Controller -->
>   addaction --> item 1

And i want to define that routes fixed and not something like a segment route looking like that:

:module/:controller/:action

I want to end up with something like

> /
>
> /controller1/[:action[/:id]]

AND

> /backend
>
> /backend/backendcontroller/[:action[/:id]]

Myapproach was the following. The problem is now, that even the backend routes seem to match to the frontend module?! I either get a 404 with

> The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

Or

> Fatal error: Class 'ClBackend\Controller\AnswerController' not found
>   in
>   //****/*****/*****/checklistenassistent3/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 177

CLFrontend/config/module.config.php

```
return array(
        'controllers' => array(
                'invokables' => array(
                        'ClFrontend\Controller\Index' => 'ClFrontend\Controller\IndexController',
                        'ClFrontend\Controller\User' => 'ClFrontend\Controller\UserController',
                ),
        ),
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'home' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'ClFrontend\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
                'display_not_found_reason' => true,
                'display_exceptions'       => true,
                'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
                'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
                'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
                'template_map' => array(
                        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/cl-frontend/layout/layout.phtml',
                        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/cl-frontend/index/index.phtml',
                        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/cl-frontend/error/404.phtml',
                        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/cl-frontend/error/index.phtml',
                ),
                'template_path_stack' => array(
                        __DIR__ . '/../view',
                ),
        ),
);
```

CLBackend/config/module.config.php

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                    'ClBackend\Controller\Answer'       => 'ClBackend\Controller\AnswerController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\AnswerGroup'  => 'ClBackend\Controller\AnswerGroupController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\Category'     => 'ClBackend\Controller\CategoryController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\Checklist'    => 'ClBackend\Controller\ChecklistController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\Index'        => 'ClBackend\Controller\IndexController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\Question'     => 'ClBackend\Controller\QuestionController',
                    'ClBackend\Controller\User'         => 'ClBackend\Controller\UserController',
            ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'backend' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/backend',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true
                ),
                'child_routes' => array (
                    'answer' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/answer/:action/:id',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\Answer',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'answergroup' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/answergroup/:action/:id',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\AnswerGroup',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'category' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/category/:action/:id',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\Category',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'checklist' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/checklist/:action/:id',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\Checklist',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'question' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/question/:action/:id',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\Question',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'user' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/user/:action[/:id]',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'ClBackend\Controller\User',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: read my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443166/zend-framework-2-default-module/12443383#12443383

Comment: " there is no such thing as 'module' from your code perspective. Module registers resources on startup and it is no longer relevant after that point. In zf2 you specify exact controller by class or alias name under which controller registered with controllerManager"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 - Multiple modules by URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079264/zend-framework-2-multiple-modules-by-url)

Comment: @Xerkus I edited my question, to clarify the difference from the mentioned threads

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Controller factory? It would allow you to match a single route and use logic to decide on which controller to use.

For example your route could look like:

```
'backend-default' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/:controller_type[/:action][/id]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'controller' => 'MyFactory'
        ),
    ),
),
```

If this route was matched then the Controller factory (MyFactory) would be used - within this factory you can gain access to the route match parameters. Using these parameters you should be able to return the appropriate controller.

You could even pass in an additional parameter signifying it's a backend controller (and use a single factory).

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyFactoryController implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // $serviceLocator is a Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager
        $app = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('application');
        $routeMatch = $app->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();

        var_dump($routeMatch);

        /**
         * Create controller based off $routeMatch params
         */

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

The controller factory would allow you to lookup the controller_type variable to a valid class name - or prefix an invokable name to controller_type.

I'm not sure I'd take this route myself but I hope this is somewhat useful for what you are trying to achieve.